# How to add safety to line voltage connected to D-SUB?

Tags: circuit-protection

Pins 13, 14, and 15 on the D-SUB connecter will be connected to 120AC line voltage when their respective relays are on. I can imagine a situation where line is shorted to neutral (dirty connector, bent pins, etc) and I'd like to get ahead of that issue. Can I simply add a fuse, maybe with a fuse holder between line and relay common?

[image: speed breeder control schematic]

Per the accepted answer. I decided to use 4 panel mounted NEMA 5-15 outlets and just plug the pump, fans, etc into the outlets.

Comment: Is the D-Sub connector rated for that voltage, at the expected current? BTW, would someone working on the system *expect* 120 VAC on such a connector???

Comment: The D-Sub is rated for 250V 2.5A. This is a prototype that only I will be interacting with. The requirements are for computer fans, aquarium pumps, etc. that I just have around. The final version wont have 120AC hanging around on a D-Sub, rather IEC 320 for power input and on board power supply distributing DC. For this one I'm using an external 24V power supply. But good points, I might consider Deutsch connectors or some other method If I can't get this reliably safe. The D-Sub was to simplify connections and make it cheaper :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd not put mains on a DSUB-xx (and I've been putting mains on things for 50+ years :-) ).

EXCEPT,  back of brain says that you can (or may be able to) get ones with mains rated shrouded contacts - these (if they exist) are super rare and no standard.

For a prototype, unless you need the "all connect together aspects" of a single connector, I'd use two connectors, or some other connector. It's doable, but "hairy".

The safest way of ensuring mains does not get out of control people-wise is to use an earth leak circuit breaker (ELCB) / ground fault interrupter (GFI).
That saves lives but NOT equipment -  a person will feel a shock* but the mains will be interrupted fast enough to (almost always) not be killed. (*Ask me how I know :-) ).
BUT equipment will usually be damaged.

A fuse will also open the circuit - but will not usually save lives or equipment downstream of the fault.

A polyfuse protected circuit will limit current, but still kill you.

GFI/ELCB for life protection and maybe a tranzorb for energy absorption MAY prevent damage.

---

A large range of subminiature connectors with various add in contacts - usually aimed at high current or coaxial [here](https://www.pinterest.nz/pin/626492998135138843/?lp=true)

Not what you want, but shows what people do ...

[image]

And ...

(I have no involvement whatsoever with "Signal Origin" - they just seemed to have parts worth using as examples.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! I will definitely be taking your advice. 50+ experience sharing with 1 year of experience is why I love this communities.